# "Not Found" error when uploading media files

Tags: media-library, permissions

I have a photo item with a file field that I can upload to a specific folder in my media library just fine on our development server, but when I try to do this on our staging server, It allows me to click upload, and seems to show progress of the upload but then gives me the error "not found" in the CMS.  I don't see any error in the log files and when I look in the Access Viewer the user in question has create and read access to the folder.  I initially thought I was able to do this as a super admin user, but I just now confirmed that this error is showing up for admin users as well.

Comment: In access viewer did you check media folder access as well and you have "Read" and "Create" access.? in both content folder as well as media folder. Also what version of sitecore it is.

Comment: 8.2.  The folder in question has read and create access for the user in question in the access viewer.  I'm not exaclty sure what you mean by "media folder access"

Comment: "I have a photo item with a file field that I can upload to a specific folder in my media library" - question is have you checked the specific media folder access where you are going to upload file.?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, in the access viewer the folder that the file is being uploaded to has create and read access for the user who is doing the uploading (but is not able to).

Comment: what roles does this user have? is it sitecore/Author? If there is nothing shown in Sitecore logs, what is shown in Console in Dev Tools?

Comment: Does it occur in all environments? Did you check both Sitecore logs/app insights/event viewer? I think we're still curious what "regular user" means. This may be a good case to use a HAMMER. Create new user, assign every role you can but don't make them an administrator. Ideally, that works. Then start the laborious task of removing roles until it stops working. At the very least, this approach should cross off roles/permissioning as an issue.

Comment: @jrap It is only happening in one environment.  As I mentioned I checked the logs but don't see any errors there.  I haven't checked the event viewer, so will do that next.  By "regular user" I mean not a super admin.  The roles they inherit include Sitecore Client Authoring, Sitecore Client Publishing, Sitecore Local Adnministrators, Sitecore Client Users, Designer, Analytics Personalization, Author, Analytics Testing, Sitecore Client Securing, Sitecore Client Social Authoring, Sitecore Client Account Managing.  HAMMER, huh?

Comment: So, it turns out that I was wrong and that I'm getting the same error as a super admin user as well.  I've updated the question.

Comment: @LeviWallach if it is reproducible only on one environment, is it an environment that has a proxy or load balancer or CDN? Chances are that something is interfering. 
And "Not Found" is it the exact wording of the error, without any additional info, have you checked in Console in Dev Tools?

Comment: Check write access to the `<webroot>\App_Data` directory, as well as `<webroot>\App_Data\MediaCache` directory. This second directory is used during upload, even though you are likely storing media assets in the database. Specifically, it will upload new files to the `<webroot>\App_Data\MediaCache\shell\<some subfolder>` directory. It will create a new `some subfolder` so ensure create access is available as well.

Comment: Start with the `everyone` user (hammer). Then back off to your Application Pool identity/Network Service/IIS_IUSRS/etc as needed.

Comment: It looks like this was my own fault - I was not changing the Destination via the Change Destination button because I thought I'd basically done that by hitting the tree view and highlighting the folder before hitting Upload Media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, apparently I was doing something out of order that was
    causing the issue.  Apparently you have to:

1. Click Browse on the File field of the template
2. Click the Upload Media Button
3. Hit Change Destination and pick the folder and navigating to the
   folder that you want to put it in.
4. Click Browse Media files and pick your file to upload.

However, I was doing this:

1. Click Browse on the File FIeld of the Template.
2. Click the tree view icon
3. Navigating and highlighting the folder (but not clicking the Select
   button)
4. Clicking the Upload media button.
5. Clicking Browse for media Files
6. Picking the file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample set of roles we have issued in the past without any user complaints:

sitecore\Author

sitecore\Analytics Testing

sitecore\Analytics Personalization

sitecore\Sitecore Client Maintaining

sitecore\Sitecore Client Users

sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing

sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring

sitecore\Designer

Please check the [Sitecore Roles guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html) to ensure that these roles meet your security requirements before making the change.

Comment: The user has most of these, but I also just found that super admins also get the same error when uploading an image.

Comment: @LeviWallach what happens if you try to do this in a private browser tab?

Comment: do you mean incognito tab? Unfortunately that's disabled on our machines, so I can't test it, and again, it's not an issue on our development machine.  I also only have a few extensions active - Google Docs and McAffee DLP Endpoint.  IE 11 does the same thing...